# Print lines of a file in reverse order using recursion - Do I understand correctly?

Tags: java, file, recursion

Goal: Print the line of a file in reverse order using recursion.

Here my two implementations- `printReverse0` and `printReverse1`.
As you've seen the code, the only difference is storing the `input.nextLine()` in local variable String line which makes storing the each line in each stack for each recursive call and print it while bubble up in printReverse1.

However, I expected that printReverse0 would be working too even though I don't store each line explicitly in local variable "line" 
since each recursion call, input in the method argument is stored 
in each activation record. So when bubble up, it can print each line by using Scanner input which is stored in each activation record.

But I realized that it wouldn't proceed to the next line since printReverse0 didn't move to the next line by using `input.nextLine();` before it calls recursive method. Which means `input.nextLine()` is behaving like i+1 to go to to the next element in an array case when the arguments of recursive method is array and its index -- `void method( int[] arr, int index )`.

Which means `String line = input.nextLine()` in printReverse1 
sets to the beginning of the next line as well as stores the current line in stack. So without it, it doesn't go to the next line and just keep pointing to the first line which resulting in stack overflow ==> Do I understand correctly?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class PrintReverseFile_Rec
{
    static void printReverse0( Scanner input ) {
        if( input.hasNextLine() ) {
            printReverse0( input ); // stack overflow here!!!
            System.out.println( input.nextLine() );
        }
        return;
    }

    static void printReverse1( Scanner input ) {
        if( input.hasNextLine() ) {
            String line = input.nextLine();
            printReverse1( input );
            System.out.println( line );
        }
        return;
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        File file = new File( "test.txt" );
        Scanner input = null;

        try {
            input = new Scanner( file );
        } catch( Exception e ) {}

        printReverse0( input );
        //printReverse1( input );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. As far as I can tell your understanding is correct. The `printReverse0` method will never exit the recursion as the `hasNext` call will always be true, and this will cause the stack to overflow.